# What is The meaning of "Sorry. Your decision has not been reached"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I applied for a job online about 1/2 month, and this is what I received in my mail

YOUR APPLICATION HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY REVIEWED YOU WOULD RECEIVE AN EMAIL SHORTLY ON THE STATUS OF YOUR APPLICATION

Another one month down the line, I haven't received any email from them. But I visited their site by trying to log into my account, and this is what I saw. update illustration

Sorry. Your decision has not been reached

Please what is the meaning of the above statement regarding my application? even though there's no official statement on the site telling applicants to check their application status.

Thank you.

Comment: Do not ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much an English language question, as a generic/lazy Human Resources/Personnel question. (I'm not blaming you for asking the question, though.)

When I was job hunting about two years ago, it was extremely common for HR departments to refuse to say anything for months after receiving an application, often blowing past their self-imposed deadlines with no shame.

Answer (score 1):

The English used by the online site is poor.  Do not worry that you do not understand it.  It's not particularly understandable.

> The first message should have read -- YOUR APPLICATION HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY REVIEWED YOU <strike>WOULD</strike> WILL RECEIVE AN EMAIL SHORTLY ON THE STATUS OF YOUR APPLICATION
>
> The second message is a bit of a mystery.  I would guess that they mean -- Sorry. Your <strike>decision</strike> DESTINATION has not been reached.  Which would more likely indicate a url error as opposed to a rejection message.

Answer (score 1):

**They have not yet decided whether to hire you.**

Effectively their sentence is:

> Sorry, your decision (the decision about your application) has not been reached yet (has not been made).

It's badly constructed, and I'd be surprised if it didn't confuse most native English speakers to some extent.

A more full version should have been:

> Sorry, but we have not yet reached a decision about your application.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered the status message "*Your decision has not been reached*" is terrible English. As such, we can only guess at its meaning. However there are some common mistakes.

Here's what is wrong with it:

> "Your decision..."

A decision belongs to whoever makes it. It isn't *your* decision to have your application accepted (if only it was!).

However, it has become common for the word "decision" to be used to describe *the result* that comes from a decision. One area in which this is common is government administration, where political correctness has influenced terminology in an attempt to try and steer perceptions. For example when someone is paid state benefits (what some countries know as welfare payments) the amount they were given was historically known as an *award*, but to prevent the perception that people are *rewarded* for not working it is often referred to as a "*decision*".

In your case, I believe they are trying to say:

> We have not yet reached a decision about your application.

But because they are speaking about a decision on *your* application they have phrased it (badly) to try and indicate that it the decision *you* are waiting for.

If I am correct, then this status is still hopeful - it sounds like you are still waiting for a decision, so a decision has not yet been made on your application either way.